# See last changes in svn

Tags: svn

I paused development on a project before going on holidays. Now after a few weeks I'd like to know what were the last things in source I was working on?

Is there a chance to see e.g. in WebSVN the last changes in the whole repository?

Comment: This question text is quite confusing. Is it about SVN or WebSVN ? According to tags this should be a question about SVN command line...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you have not yet commit you last changes before vacation.
- Command line to the project folder.
- Type '`svn diff`'

If you already commit you last changes before vacation.

- Browse to your project.
- Find a link "View log". Click it.
- Select top two revision and Click "Compare Revisions" button in the bottom.
  This will show you the different between the latest and the previous revision.

Answer (score 105):

Open you working copy folder in console (terminal) and choose commands below.
To see **last changes**:
If you have **commited** last changes use:

```
svn diff -rPREV
```

If you **left changes** in working copy (that's bad practice) than use:

```
svn diff
```

To see **log of commits**:
If you're working in branch:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy
```

If you're working with trunk:

```
svn log | head
```

or just

```
svn log
```

Answer (score 48):

```
svn log -r {2009-09-17}:HEAD
```

where `2009-09-17` is the date you went on holiday.  To see the changed files as well as the summary, add a `-v` option:

```
svn log -r {2009-09-17}:HEAD -v
```

I haven't used WebSVN but there will be a log viewer somewhere that does the equivalent of these commands under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a working copy then svn status will help.

```
svn status -u -v
```

The `--show-updates` (`-u`) option contacts the repository and adds information about things that are out of date.

Answer (score 5):

```
svn log -v
```

Comment: Could you add more detail/explanation?

Answer (score 3):

`svn log` - I'm sure WebSVN has some feature for that too.

The "View Log" link near the center-top of the WebSVN overview shows the svn-log.  However, the user-interface isn't exactly brilliant; I much prefer TortoiseSVN's log viewer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CommitMonitor](http://tools.stefankueng.com/CommitMonitor.html). This little tool uses very little RAM and notifies you of all the commits you've missed.

Comment: +1: CommitMonitor is small and unobtrusive, and I've found it handy for letting you get a quick glance at what others are doing in the repository as well as seeing changes in your area of code after a break.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do "svn update" before you do "svn log".  Without running update, often I cannot see the last few commits in the log.

This is the svn version on my machine.

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.13.0 (r1867053)
compiled May 12 2022, 20:47:08 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu